# Attaching another modem to an iPhone or gPhone

Tags: android, iphone, modem, satellite

I have an idea in mind where a device such as an iPhone or gPhone is attached to a satellite modem for use when out of GPRS/UMTS range.

Would such an idea be feasible, and what are the high level steps towards implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1705137&tstart=150

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the Apple side, I don't think they want you to connect to other network access points.

On the gPhone / Android side, if your sat phone supported bluetooth tethering, it should be possible, maybe with something like this:

http://www.satelliteworldstore.com/store/cart.php?target=product&product_id=16179&category_id=268

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on the android platform, assuming your satelite phone has a bluetooth modem, you will have to wait till they actually integrate bluetooth properly into the API, unless you want to do some lower level programming.